# Add user to sharepoint group

Tags: client-object-model, sharepoint-online

I want to add a user to SharePoint group (in another site collection) using JavaScript API.

Here's my code

```
 var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext("https://MYURL/sites/dev2/");
            var groupCollection = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups();
            // Get the visitors group, assuming its ID is 4.
            visitorsGroup = groupCollection.getByName("Editorial Workflow Approvers");
            user = clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
            var userCollection = visitorsGroup.get_users();
            //userCollection.add(user);

            //clientContext.load(user);

        //test
            var peoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePickerDiv_TopSpan;

        // Get information about all users.
            var users = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
            var userInfo = '';
            var MyFoundUser;
            for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                var user = users[i];

                //Test
                var UserLoginName = user["Key"].split('|')[2];

                MyFoundUser = clientContext.get_web().ensureUser(user["Key"]);
                clientContext.load(MyFoundUser);
                //Test
                break;
            }
        //test

            userCollection.add(MyFoundUser);

            clientContext.load(visitorsGroup);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function onQuerySucceeded() {
                alert(user.get_title() + " added to group " + visitorsGroup.get_title());
            }), Function.createDelegate(this, function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
                alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
            }));
```

I get following error: "Request failed. The parameter loginname cannot be empty or bigger than 251 characters".

When i add current user which i get in 'user' variable it works fine.

just to add i have used both "userLoginName" variable and "user["Key"]" (in current code). both fail

Please suggest what i am doing wrong. Or if there's any other way to achieve this please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the MyFoundUser to the context: clientContext.load(MyFoundUser). I am looking at my code which does similar, but I add the user in one request, and then add the user to a group in another request. You might have to make 2 calls, but I think loading the user into the context should work.

HTH

Comment: hi david. I had already added MyFoundUser in clientcontext (Please see the code). anyways, I achieved my functionality by calling sharepoint soap service (using SPServices). Thanks for your comment..